# This code ran fine in Colab but didn't in Jupyter, what's wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, calculus

I'm a newbie and very lost. The code ran fine in Colab but not in Jupyter, the error message says

```
<ipython-input-39-857dd8605500>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  def f(x, y): return np.sqrt(9-x**2-y**2)
<ipython-input-39-857dd8605500>:8: UserWarning: Z contains NaN values. This may result in rendering artifacts.
  ax.plot_surface(X, Y, f(X, Y))
```

Here is the code:

```
def f(x, y): return np.sqrt(9 - x**2 - y**2)
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, f(X, Y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function creates negative values inside the square root function. That is not defined with real numbers.